# Elastic vector tile api - field wildcard in request body

Tags: elasticsearch, gis

I have certain fields named accordingly: attr_name, attr_type, ... and I want them all embedded in the hits layer of the vector tile.
After reading the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-vector-tile-api.html#search-vector-tile-api-request-body), I would form the body as follows with a wildcard.

```json
{
  "fields": ["attr_*"]
}
```

However that returns none of the fields. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, unfortunately it seems to be a bug and wildcards are not working in this API. I have opened an issue to address it:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/85592